# Theano windows installation - Configuring the Environment

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to install Theano on windows with Anaconda and I'm stuck at the "Configuring the Environment" step. The instructions [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html) say: `The script assumes that you installed WinPython distribution, update the winpython line otherwise.` The line in question is

```
CALL %SCISOFT%\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\scripts\env.bat
```

What am I supposed to change this to if I'm using Anaconda instead of WinPython?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to install ["Theano on Windows with Anaconda"](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows)

After Anaconda is installed:

1. `$ conda install mingw libpython`
2. `$ pip install theano`

Then maybe, you needn't do anything else, just test it.

Answer (score 0):

The dedicated Anaconda paragraph is not correct ?

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#alternative-anaconda